# concat variables in handlebars expressions

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

Is it somehow possible to concat variables in a handlebars expression - for instance in an each?

```
{{#each foo/cat{{bar.id}}}}
```

Result of the above should be the same as to write

```
{{#each foo/cat2}}
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I think if you are having this problem it is a clue that your data structure needs changing. That notwithstanding, I believe there is no way to arrive at a solution without creating a custom helper. I think the simplest way would be to create a helper to concatenate the prefix and the id, and then to use the built-in [lookup](http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html#lookup) helper to access the member of `foo`:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('concat', function(prefix, id) {
    return (prefix + id);
});

{{#each (lookup foo (concat 'cat' bar.id))}}

{{/each}}
```